# Why does my application's IP address not change on subsequent requests?

Tags: heroku

As far as I know, Heroku has dynamic outbound IP addresses. But when I try to make a PHP script that requests `https://ipinfo.io/ip` via curl the IP doesn't seem to change.

When I push new commits the IP address *does* change, and when I run `heroku run bash` and run `curl` from there I always see a new IP.

Why does the IP not change when I run my PHP script from my browser, but it does change when I run `curl` via bash?

Comment: @HlmiAzizi SO is for asking specific questions not asking for opinions or documentation. You should find this on the Heroku web site not in here. You can always refer to the Help Center to learn more about asking questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run something via `heroku run` [it runs in a one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno). This dyno is separate from the dyno(s) where your web server is running. It will therefore have a different IP address. Each time you run `heroku run bash` you get a brand new one-off dyno, resulting in a new IP address.

> When I push new commits the IP address *does* change

Similarly, pushing changes to Heroku causes a new slug to be built and your application to be restarted.

You should be able to see similar behaviour if you simply restart your application, e.g. via [`heroku restart`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts).